# Different Celery instance objects using same broker - Is that a good practice?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I was wondering, is it a good practice, to have different Celery instance objects using same broker?

Currently, I have a rabbitmq, acted as single broker shared among 3 instances of Celery. My Celery instances are as follow

- `insider_transaction` - Fixed schedule worker. Run every minute
- `earning` - Worker created by web server.
- `stock_price` - Worker created by web server.

I designed every worker runs in their own docker container. I expect 3 workers will run independent from each others.

However, I realize that is not the case!

**For instance, `earning` worker will mistakenly receive messages which are suppose to be received only by `stock_price` or `insider_transaction`.**

You will see this kind of message received by `earning` worker.

```
earning_1              | The message has been ignored and discarded.
earning_1              |
earning_1              | Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
earning_1              | Or maybe you're using relative imports?
earning_1              |
earning_1              | Please see
earning_1              | http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
earning_1              | for more information.
earning_1              |
earning_1              | The full contents of the message body was:
earning_1              | '[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)
earning_1              | Traceback (most recent call last):
earning_1              |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 561, in on_task_received
earning_1              |     strategy = strategies[type_]
earning_1              | KeyError: 'insider_transaction.run'
```

and this

```
earning_1              | The message has been ignored and discarded.
earning_1              |
earning_1              | Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
earning_1              | Or maybe you're using relative imports?
earning_1              |
earning_1              | Please see
earning_1              | http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
earning_1              | for more information.
earning_1              |
earning_1              | The full contents of the message body was:
earning_1              | '[[2, 3], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (81b)
earning_1              | Traceback (most recent call last):
earning_1              |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 561, in on_task_received
earning_1              |     strategy = strategies[type_]
earning_1              | KeyError: 'stock_price.mul'
```

I don't expect such to happen. In my web server side code (Flask). I wrote

```
celery0 = Celery('earning',
                broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL,
                backend=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)

celery1 = Celery('stock_price',
                broker=CELERY_BROKER_URL,
                backend=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)

@app.route('/do_work/<int:param1>/<int:param2>')
def do_work(param1,param2):
    task0 = celery0.send_task('earning.add', args=[param1, param2], kwargs={})

    task1 = celery1.send_task('stock_price.mul', args=[param1, param2], kwargs={})
```

Hence, I expect `earning` worker will only receive `earning` message, not `stock_price` nor `insider_transaction` message.

May I know, why this problem occur? Is it not possible for different instance of Celery sharing single broker?

A project which demonstrates this problem can be checkout from https://github.com/yccheok/celery-hello-world

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
http://localhost:5000/do_work/2/3
docker-compose up earning
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using routing keys? You can use [routing keys](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#exchanges-queues-and-routing-keys) to tell the exchange which tasks to handle with which queues. Setting these in your celery configs may help to prevent the wrong messages from being consumed by the wrong workers.

Comment: I'm not using routing key and can hardly understand the idea behind routing keys. However, I'm able to solve it partially using "queue name". Do you know is using queue name a correct solution? These are my changes - https://github.com/yccheok/celery-hello-world/commit/55d55dd4ca06402ad5e65d2bce92c03096eeda61 However, I still having problem to make scheduled worker work on specified queue name.

Comment: I think I had figured out why my scheduled task is not running this time. As, all the workers is using named queue. I need to prepare both beat job and worker job, in order for scheduled task to work properly. See my changes - https://github.com/yccheok/celery-hello-world/commit/b1797c43da808dd2c8c9c82ff5917b93e17be373

Comment: Setting the queue name and the location of the config file as you have done is a fine way to do it. For more info on celery, you might like this explanation, which has been helpful to me in the past: https://abhishek-tiwari.com/amqp-rabbitmq-and-celery-a-visual-guide-for-dummies/